# yii2 multiple select with image

Tags: php, jquery, yii, yii2, multiple-select

I used Yii2 multiple selection dropdown with image , it is working fine at create but not showing me selected values on update...
Form:

```
<?php
    $allProducts = Product::find()->where('active = 1')->all();
    $prArr = array();
    if ($allProducts) {
        foreach ($allProducts as $allProduct) {
            echo '<option value="' . $allProduct->id . '" style="color: #000; height: 50px; padding-left: 70px;padding-top: 15px;background-image: url(\'' . $allProduct->getThumb() . '\');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 65px auto;">' . $allProduct->title . '</option>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Controller:

```
$oldRels = ProductRelated::find()->where('main_product_id = :main_product_id', ['main_product_id' => $model->id])->all();
if ($oldRels) {
    foreach ($oldRels as $oldRel) {
        $oldRel->delete();
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['relProducts']) and ! empty($_POST['relProducts'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['relProducts'] as $relProduct_id) {
        $relProduct = new ProductRelated;
        $relProduct->main_product_id = $model->id;
        $relProduct->rel_product_id = $relProduct_id;
        $relProduct->save(false);
    }
}
```

How I can show multi selected values in dropdown with images when I update my recored?

Comment: You have to add selected attribute in options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
 <select id="relProductSelect" name="relProducts[]" multiple>
     <?php 
     $allProducts = Product::find()->where('active = 1')->all();
     $arrRelatedProducts = ArrayHelper::map(ProductRelated::find()->where('main_product_id = :main_product_id', ['main_product_id' => $model->id])->all(), 'rel_product_id', 'rel_product_id');
     if($allProducts){
       foreach($allProducts as $allProduct){
        if(in_array($allProduct->id, $arrRelatedProducts)){
            echo '<option value="'.$allProduct->id.'" selected style="color: #000; height: 50px; padding-left: 70px;padding-top: 15px;background-image: url(\''.$allProduct->getThumb().'\');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 65px auto;">'.$allProduct->title.'</option>';    
        }else{
          echo '<option value="'.$allProduct->id.'" style="color: #000; height: 50px; padding-left: 70px;padding-top: 15px;background-image: url(\''.$allProduct->getThumb().'\');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 65px auto;">'.$allProduct->title.'</option>';
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                ?>
                </select>
```